# each loop not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am calling a jquery function  from .aspx page as follows

```
 <body onload="JavaScript:createPanels('[{a,b,c,d,e}]')">
```

in my jquery I have function defined as

```
function createPanels(requiredButtons) {
    var abc = JSON.stringify(requiredButtons)
    abc.each(function (key, value) {
        alert(value);
    });

}
```

Now the issue is that I am not getting any alert.

Can any one point me where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you want to call `each` like that it'd have to be on a jquery object, so `$(abc).each`. Otherwise you would call `$.each(abc, ...)`. It's in the docs.

Comment: if you're looking for the javascript [array iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), you need to use `.forEach`

Answer (score 1):

Thats not how `$.each` is to be used:

Try this:

```
$.each(abc, function (key, value) {
    alert(value);
});
```

It will alert each character in the string.

Comment: I tried this but now its giving me alert for each single character in "{a,b,c,d}" including quotes and commas and braces. I only want alert for a b c and d

Answer (score 1):

Several issues there.

a. This is not JSON `[{a,b,c,d,e}]`

If you really want to do it on the body element then this is how to do it:

```
<body onload="JavaScript:createPanels('{&#34;posts&#34;: [{&#34;key&#34;:&#34;value&#34;}, {&#34;key&#34;:&#34;value&#34;}]}')">
```

This is not a really good idea, so you call it in a jquery page load handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //create the JSON object here
  //call the function here
});
```

b. Change your script too:

```
function createPanels(requiredButtons){
    var abc = JSON.parse(requiredButtons);
    $(abc).each(function (key, value) {
         alert(value);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid JSON format. Json Format is like as below:

```
 var obj = {
     "flammable": "inflammable",
      "duh": "no duh"
   };
```

Then Use as below:

```
 $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
     alert( key + ": " + value );
  });
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

"{a,b,c,d}" is not a object that's why your code is not working.

Second point is : **Use jQuery.each() for iterating a collection.**

Try to put it in this form :

```
var x= ['a','b','c','d','e'];
jQuery.each(x,function (key, value) {
        console.log(value);
});
```

It will return **a,b,c,d,e** as you want.

Here is the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MzxPk/)

Answer (score 0):

I lurve jQuery and everything, but there's no need to invoke it to iterate an array.

```
abc.forEach( function (elem) {
    console.log(elem);
});
```

should work, once you've tidied up your JSON thing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your valuable suggessions
I solved the problem as

.aspx page

```
<body onload="JavaScript:createPanels('a,b,c,d,e')">
```

jquery

```
function createPanels(requiredButtons) {
    var abc = requiredButtons.split(',');
    $.each(abc, function (key, value) {
        alert(value);
    });
```

}